# matlab interrupt throw exception

Tags: matlab, exception

I would like to catch any calls to <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> as an exception, so that I deal with interrupts in a less disruptive way. The only discussion I found online was [this thread on the matlab exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252760) from 2009. I was wondering whether anyone knows of new solution that may have come up in the more recent versions of matlab. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, MATLAB interprets it as an interrupt. I don't think there is a way for you to catch the call and do something like jump to a different loop or so, for example.

However, you can use the function [`onCleanup`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/oncleanup.html) to do operations like close open file handles, delete temporary files, write a log, display a message, or even save the workspace before MATLAB interrupts. However, it needs to be called from inside a function.

Here's a simple illustrative example

```
function test
currentDir=pwd;
cd 'path to some folder'
c=onCleanup(@()cd(currentDir));

for i=1:...
    %#some computations here
end
```

So when this function runs and you interrupt, it brings you back to the same folder you were in when you ran it. This is nice to have so that you aren't stuck in some random folder and you need to type in manually every time.

Comment: That was the gist of what was posted in the link to Matlab Central, but thanks for the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the `onCleanup` method, note that you can write your own similar object by deriving from `handle`, and implementing a `delete` method. The doc is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/handle.delete.html).